# How to assign two columns with CASE in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

How can i assign values for more than one column in my `SQL query` with `CASE` statement. When i tried as shown below i am getting error.

`select case when 1=1 then 'Y' column1, 'Yes' column2 end from dual;`

`ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:

*Action:
Error at Line: 24 Column: 31`

Can you please help.

Comment: A CASE **expression** results in exactly one column - because it's **one** expression.

Comment: @teepu, For all the columns, is the condition same? and is it just one condition?

Comment: for all teh columns condition is same

Answer (score 0):

Repeat the `case`:

```
SQL> select case when 1 = 1 then 'Y'
  2              else 'N'
  3         end column1,
  4         --
  5         case when 1 = 1 then 'Y'
  6              else 'N'
  7         end column2
  8  from dual;

C C
- -
Y Y

SQL>
```

---

If you don't want to repeat it, a CTE is one option you might use:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select case when 1 = 1 then 'Y'
  3                 else 'N'
  4            end val
  5     from dual
  6    )
  7  select val as column1,
  8         val as column2
  9  from temp;

C C
- -
Y Y

SQL>
```

Or, even less typing:

```
SQL> select val as column1,
  2         val as column2
  3  from (select decode(1, 1, 'Y', 'N') va
  4        from dual);

C C
- -
Y Y

SQL>
```

Comment: actually i just wanted to avoid code repetitive, so is there way?

Comment: Yes; I added some more examples. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want:

```
select 'Y' as column1, 'Yes' as column1
from dual
where 1=1
union all
select NULL, NULL
from dual
where not (1=1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation and a `WHERE` clause:

```
select max('Y') column1, max('Yes') column2 
from dual
where 1=1
```

Result:

```
> COLUMN1 | COLUMN2
> :------ | :------
> Y       | Yes
```

Or:

```
select max('Y') column1, max('Yes') column2 
from dual
where 1=2
```

Result:

```
> COLUMN1 | COLUMN2
> :------ | :------
> null    | null
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d43d556b557e619be434494f287b7b00).